# dropdown not updating view when value in viewmodel changes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, breeze, wijmo

I have the following in my view:

```
 <div id="tbAddress" class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span11">
                <h2>Mailing Address</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">Address</div>
            <div class="span9">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: MailingAddress1 " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">Address 2</div>
            <div class="span9">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: MailingAddress2 " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">City</div>
            <div class="span9">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: MailingCity " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">State</div>
            <div class="span3">
                 <select data-bind="value: MailingState">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                    <option value="DC">Dist of Columbia</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">Zip Code</div>
            <div class="span3">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: MailingZIP " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">Phone</div>
            <div class="span3">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Phone " />
            </div>
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">Fax</div>
            <div class="span3">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Fax " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">Email</div>
            <div class="span9">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Email " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">Website</div>
            <div class="span9">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Website " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span7">
                <h2>Physical Address</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <button type="submit" data-bind="click: $parent.sameAsMailingAddressClicked">Physical Address Same as Mailing</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">Address</div>
            <div class="span9">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: PhysicalAddress1 " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">Address 2</div>
            <div class="span9">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: PhysicalAddress2 " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">City</div>
            <div class="span9">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: PhysicalCity " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">State</div>
            <div class="span3">
                <select data-bind="value: PhysicalState">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                    <option value="DC">Dist of Columbia</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="span2">Zip Code</div>
            <div class="span3">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: PhysicalZIP " />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button Same As Mailing then calls this function in my viewmodel

```
function doSameMailing(){

    var ap = self.activePermit();

    ap.PhysicalAddress1(ap.MailingAddress1());
    ap.PhysicalAddress2(ap.MailingAddress2());
    ap.PhysicalCity(ap.MailingCity());
    ap.PhysicalState(ap.MailingState());
    ap.PhysicalZIP(ap.MailingZIP());

}
```

In the viewAttached handler, I have the following code to make the inputs and select statement utilize the wijmo controls.

```
 $('select').wijcombobox();
 $(':text').wijtextbox();
```

I want to copy the mailing address into the Physical Address fields, this works for all but the `PhysicalState` field.   If I check the viewmodel, the Physical State value is changed in the viewmodel but the view does not update the value in the select.  If I hit the save button the PhysicalState field gets saved with the proper value.

I am using the following:

- wijmo professional 2013.v1.2
- durandal
- breeze
- jquery 1.90.1
- jqueryui 1.10.2
- knockout 2.2.1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is because the wijmo combobox hides the select and renders its own html.  The supported way to set the dropdown value is to use the plugin's option method, like so:

```
$("#physicalStatesSelect").wijcombobox("option", "selectedValue", "TN")
```

In order to make this work seamlessly using knockout, you'll need to create a custom binding and use that to manage the plugin.

Here's a simple example of a binding that you could use:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.wijmocombobox = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        //create the element
        $(element).wijcombobox();
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        //update logic
        var selectedValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).wijcombobox("option", "selectedValue", selectedValue)
    }
};
```

With that binding your html looks like this:

```
<select data-bind="wijmocombobox: PhysicalState">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Notice that the `wijcombobox` is getting created in the init, so you should remove the current call to `$('select').wijcombobox();`

In order to get your PhysicalState view model property updated from the control, it may be necessary to set up an event handler inside your binding's 'init' method.  This handler can listen for changes in the element, and manually set the PhysicalState value with the selectedValue from wijmocombobox.  Something like:

```
var selectedValueObservable = valueAccessor();
var newValue = $(element).wijcombobox("option", "selectedValue");
selectedValueObservable(newValue);
```

Comment: I did not need to create a custom binding,  The code worked without one.   I did have to set my viewmodel value to the correct state,  then use that in the statement.  My line ended up looking like this: ap.PhysicalState(ap.MailingState());     $('#cboPhysicalState').wijcombobox('option', 'selectedValue', ap.PhysicalState());

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why it is not working but I think that it would be better if you use the special binding implemented by knockout for the select html element.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

I hope this will help you to solve the problem.

---EDIT--

I have changed the link, I have written the wrong link.

Comment: The selectedOptions is meant for a multi select dropdown, which is not the case for me.  That is why I am binding to the value property.  I had tried putting the state list in array on the viewmodel and binding to it with the options property,  but had the same issue.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: ok, sorry, I have confused the binding. Have you se this binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html I have used that two times for implementing a combobox. If you want I can add some examples.

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdown is being styled in the sense that they are hiding it, I have found that knockout does not update from their calls.

Take chosen for example:

```
$('#field').chosen().change(function(){
  $('#field').change();
});
```

By triggering the original fields change on a chosen change I was able to get the knockout value to update.  I have never used Wijmo but it appears to be doing something similar with styling so more than likely it is not triggering the dropdown the way knockout expects it to.

**EDIT** re-reading your question I realize you were asking the opposite of my answer.  Assuming you have an explicit copying event you can trigger a wijmo update (again only have chosen experience but I assume they having something similar:

```
//On update
$('#field').trigger('liszt:update');
```

This tells chosen that the select has changed and you need to update.